# Reset Retry Counter, error: "6d00" -> Instruction code not supported or invalid

Tags: authentication, smartcard, apdu, pin-code

I have this command as reference:
XX 2C 03 XX

When I send the command: "00 2C 03 01 00" I'm getting error 6d00 (Instruction code not supported or invalid)

Important: I am in a test environment, I am studying the APDU commands.
After testing questions I sent the command to verify the PIN containing an invalid PIN 3 times in a row.
Original PIN: 1574
P1 = 0x15
P2 = 0x15
Commands:

```
>> 0x00,0x20,0x00,0x80,0x08,0x24,p1,p2,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF
<< 63c2
>> 0x00,0x20,0x00,0x80,0x08,0x24,p1,p2,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF
<< 63c1
>> 0x00,0x20,0x00,0x80,0x08,0x24,p1,p2,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF
<< 63c0
```

After that, I run the command again:

```
>> 0x00,0x20,0x00,0x80,0x08,0x24,p1,p2,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF
<< 6983
```

I want to reset the counter (Reset Retry Counter), so that I can verify the PIN again, for this purpose I am executing the following command:

```
>> 00 2C 03 00
<< 6d00
```

**Why am I getting this error: "6d00"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was forgetting the PUK code, problem solved!
The correct is:

```
CL ='00' -
INS='2C' - RESET RETRY COUNTER
P1 = either
'00' - Data contains PUK and new PIN
'01' - Data contains PUK only
P2 ='01' - Key Reference of the PIN (as <01>)
Data = either
       PUK | NewPIN, if P1='00'
       PUK         , if P1='01'
```